# Manual event-handling in Qt/embedded,(without using QApplication:exec() )

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt4, linux-kernel

I am writing a Qt/embedded GUI Application.But calling the **exec()** should be avoided as i dont want to leave the responsibility of event handling, solely on QWS(Qt Windowing System).Rather it will be advantageous for me, if can manually call the event-handler(e.g. **processEvents**) when necessary?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here. Could you perhaps give an example of what you are trying to do and where you've run into trouble?

Comment: The event loop is basically the heart of Qt. Why would you want to stop it? What are you trying to achieve? If you want to filter out events, such as user events, there are various ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is what you want, from [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405544&seqNum=2):

> We can subclass QApplication and reimplement notify().
>
> Qt calls QApplication::notify() to send out an event. Reimplementing
>   this function is the only way to get all the events, before any event
>   filters get the opportunity to look at them. Event filters are
>   generally more useful, because there can be any number of concurrent
>   event filters, but only one notify() function.

Then I guess you could buffer the events as they come in, and subclass `QApplication` to create a custom `processEvents`-like function, to send them out when you want to.  But as others note it's not really clear why you'd want to override QWS.